# how to add multiple canvas on same html page

Tags: html

I [copied a puzzle code](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-an-html5-canvas-tile-swapping-puzzle--active-10747). Now i need to add more puzzles in the same page how i can do that with this javascript. Please anyone guide me to how to handle this code for making multiple puzzles, I have basic skill in javascript, I am trying to add another variable for new puzzle it's not working...

```js
const PUZZLE_DIFFICULTY = 2;
const PUZZLE_HOVER_TINT = '#009900';

var _stage;
var _canvas;

var _img;
var _pieces;
var _puzzleWidth;
var _puzzleHeight;
var _pieceWidth;
var _pieceHeight;
var _currentPiece;
var _currentDropPiece;

var _mouse;

function init() {
  _img = new Image();
  _img.addEventListener('load', onImage, false);
  _img.src = "http://lorempixel.com/output/animals-q-g-640-480-3.jpg";
}

function onImage(e) {
  _pieceWidth = Math.floor(_img.width / PUZZLE_DIFFICULTY)
  _pieceHeight = Math.floor(_img.height / PUZZLE_DIFFICULTY)
  _puzzleWidth = _pieceWidth * PUZZLE_DIFFICULTY;
  _puzzleHeight = _pieceHeight * PUZZLE_DIFFICULTY;
  setCanvas();
  initPuzzle();
}

function setCanvas() {
  _canvas = document.getElementById('puzzle');
  _stage = _canvas.getContext('2d');
  _canvas.width = _puzzleWidth;
  _canvas.height = _puzzleHeight;
  _canvas.style.border = "1px solid black";
}

function initPuzzle() {
  _pieces = [];
  _mouse = {
    x: 0,
    y: 0
  };
  _currentPiece = null;
  _currentDropPiece = null;
  _stage.drawImage(_img, 0, 0, _puzzleWidth, _puzzleHeight, 0, 0, _puzzleWidth, _puzzleHeight);
  createTitle("Click to Start Puzzle");
  buildPieces();
}

function createTitle(msg) {
  _stage.fillStyle = "#000000";
  _stage.globalAlpha = .4;
  _stage.fillRect(100, _puzzleHeight - 40, _puzzleWidth - 200, 40);
  _stage.fillStyle = "#FFFFFF";
  _stage.globalAlpha = 1;
  _stage.textAlign = "center";
  _stage.textBaseline = "middle";
  _stage.font = "20px Arial";
  _stage.fillText(msg, _puzzleWidth / 2, _puzzleHeight - 20);
}

function buildPieces() {
  var i;
  var piece;
  var xPos = 0;
  var yPos = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < PUZZLE_DIFFICULTY * PUZZLE_DIFFICULTY; i++) {
    piece = {};
    piece.sx = xPos;
    piece.sy = yPos;
    _pieces.push(piece);
    xPos += _pieceWidth;
    if (xPos >= _puzzleWidth) {
      xPos = 0;
      yPos += _pieceHeight;
    }
  }
  document.onmousedown = shufflePuzzle;
}

function shufflePuzzle() {
  _pieces = shuffleArray(_pieces);
  _stage.clearRect(0, 0, _puzzleWidth, _puzzleHeight);
  var i;
  var piece;
  var xPos = 0;
  var yPos = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < _pieces.length; i++) {
    piece = _pieces[i];
    piece.xPos = xPos;
    piece.yPos = yPos;
    _stage.drawImage(_img, piece.sx, piece.sy, _pieceWidth, _pieceHeight, xPos, yPos, _pieceWidth, _pieceHeight);
    _stage.strokeRect(xPos, yPos, _pieceWidth, _pieceHeight);
    xPos += _pieceWidth;
    if (xPos >= _puzzleWidth) {
      xPos = 0;
      yPos += _pieceHeight;
    }
  }
  document.onmousedown = onPuzzleClick;
}

function onPuzzleClick(e) {
  if (e.layerX || e.layerX == 0) {
    _mouse.x = e.layerX - _canvas.offsetLeft;
    _mouse.y = e.layerY - _canvas.offsetTop;
  } else if (e.offsetX || e.offsetX == 0) {
    _mouse.x = e.offsetX - _canvas.offsetLeft;
    _mouse.y = e.offsetY - _canvas.offsetTop;
  }
  _currentPiece = checkPieceClicked();
  if (_currentPiece != null) {
    _stage.clearRect(_currentPiece.xPos, _currentPiece.yPos, _pieceWidth, _pieceHeight);
    _stage.save();
    _stage.globalAlpha = .9;
    _stage.drawImage(_img, _currentPiece.sx, _currentPiece.sy, _pieceWidth, _pieceHeight, _mouse.x - (_pieceWidth / 2), _mouse.y - (_pieceHeight / 2), _pieceWidth, _pieceHeight);
    _stage.restore();
    document.onmousemove = updatePuzzle;
    document.onmouseup = pieceDropped;
  }
}

function checkPieceClicked() {
  var i;
  var piece;
  for (i = 0; i < _pieces.length; i++) {
    piece = _pieces[i];
    if (_mouse.x < piece.xPos || _mouse.x > (piece.xPos + _pieceWidth) || _mouse.y < piece.yPos || _mouse.y > (piece.yPos + _pieceHeight)) {
      //PIECE NOT HIT
    } else {
      return piece;
    }
  }
  return null;
}

function updatePuzzle(e) {
  _currentDropPiece = null;
  if (e.layerX || e.layerX == 0) {
    _mouse.x = e.layerX - _canvas.offsetLeft;
    _mouse.y = e.layerY - _canvas.offsetTop;
  } else if (e.offsetX || e.offsetX == 0) {
    _mouse.x = e.offsetX - _canvas.offsetLeft;
    _mouse.y = e.offsetY - _canvas.offsetTop;
  }
  _stage.clearRect(0, 0, _puzzleWidth, _puzzleHeight);
  var i;
  var piece;
  for (i = 0; i < _pieces.length; i++) {
    piece = _pieces[i];
    if (piece == _currentPiece) {
      continue;
    }
    _stage.drawImage(_img, piece.sx, piece.sy, _pieceWidth, _pieceHeight, piece.xPos, piece.yPos, _pieceWidth, _pieceHeight);
    _stage.strokeRect(piece.xPos, piece.yPos, _pieceWidth, _pieceHeight);
    if (_currentDropPiece == null) {
      if (_mouse.x < piece.xPos || _mouse.x > (piece.xPos + _pieceWidth) || _mouse.y < piece.yPos || _mouse.y > (piece.yPos + _pieceHeight)) {
        //NOT OVER
      } else {
        _currentDropPiece = piece;
        _stage.save();
        _stage.globalAlpha = .4;
        _stage.fillStyle = PUZZLE_HOVER_TINT;
        _stage.fillRect(_currentDropPiece.xPos, _currentDropPiece.yPos, _pieceWidth, _pieceHeight);
        _stage.restore();
      }
    }
  }
  _stage.save();
  _stage.globalAlpha = .6;
  _stage.drawImage(_img, _currentPiece.sx, _currentPiece.sy, _pieceWidth, _pieceHeight, _mouse.x - (_pieceWidth / 2), _mouse.y - (_pieceHeight / 2), _pieceWidth, _pieceHeight);
  _stage.restore();
  _stage.strokeRect(_mouse.x - (_pieceWidth / 2), _mouse.y - (_pieceHeight / 2), _pieceWidth, _pieceHeight);
}

function pieceDropped(e) {
  document.onmousemove = null;
  document.onmouseup = null;
  if (_currentDropPiece != null) {
    var tmp = {
      xPos: _currentPiece.xPos,
      yPos: _currentPiece.yPos
    };
    _currentPiece.xPos = _currentDropPiece.xPos;
    _currentPiece.yPos = _currentDropPiece.yPos;
    _currentDropPiece.xPos = tmp.xPos;
    _currentDropPiece.yPos = tmp.yPos;
  }
  resetPuzzleAndCheckWin();
}

function resetPuzzleAndCheckWin() {
  _stage.clearRect(0, 0, _puzzleWidth, _puzzleHeight);
  var gameWin = true;
  var i;
  var piece;
  for (i = 0; i < _pieces.length; i++) {
    piece = _pieces[i];
    _stage.drawImage(_img, piece.sx, piece.sy, _pieceWidth, _pieceHeight, piece.xPos, piece.yPos, _pieceWidth, _pieceHeight);
    _stage.strokeRect(piece.xPos, piece.yPos, _pieceWidth, _pieceHeight);
    if (piece.xPos != piece.sx || piece.yPos != piece.sy) {
      gameWin = false;
    }
  }
  if (gameWin) {
    setTimeout(gameOver, 500);
  }
}

function gameOver() {
  document.onmousedown = null;
  document.onmousemove = null;
  document.onmouseup = null;
  initPuzzle();
  alert("you Won")
}

function shuffleArray(o) {
  for (var j, x, i = o.length; i; j = parseInt(Math.random() * i), x = o[--i], o[i] = o[j], o[j] = x);
  return o;
}
```

```html
<body onload="init();">
  <canvas id="puzzle"></canvas>
</body>
```

Comment: Prabhu, Your code doesn't work. Please check it again. I have put it into the snippet.

Comment: @RevtiShah Yes it does. Just needed an image.

Comment: @mplungjan okay Thanks.

Comment: The code originates from https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-an-html5-canvas-tile-swapping-puzzle--active-10747 and you will need to move the hardcoded `_canvas = document.getElementById('puzzle');` and the hardcoded image too

Comment: @mplungjan why removed? He wants more puzzles on one page. So we can make more canvas using different ids.

Comment: @RevtiShah MOVE to some initialiser

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205204/discussion-between-revti-shah-and-mplungjan).

Comment: @mplungjan Should I create an array of _canvas?

Comment: I would create the canvasses on the page in the init function

Comment: i need more puzzles in one page

Comment: We know. It is not trivial to change your existing code and since you show no effort except copypasta, it is hard to get the enthusiasm to help you...